# Gradle: Change jdk

Tags: gradle

I've configure `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/home/jeusdi/java/jdk-11.0.2/
```

Nevertheless, when I perform `gradle -version`:

```
Initialized native services in: /home/jeusdi/.gradle/native

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-03-20 11:03:29 UTC
Revision:     f5c64796748a98efdbf6f99f44b6afe08492c2a0

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.18.0-16-generic amd64
```

As you can see, it's picking an 1.8 JVM, instead of my java11 I've set on `gradle.properties`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems these are different settings. Not sure, but probably `org.gradle.java.home` will be used by gradle to build the project, whereas `JAVA_HOME` to run the gradle itself - could you please verify it? Also please have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html?_ga=2.257311051.1380038345.1553243740-1137354039.1531200500):

> **org.gradle.java.home**=(path to JDK home)
>   Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location, however, depending on what your build does, using a JDK is safer. A reasonable default is derived from your environment (JAVA_HOME or the path to java) if the setting is unspecified. This does not affect the version of Java used to launch the Gradle client VM

Comment: Yes... I've changed `JAVA_HOME` and `-version` has changed. Should both be aligned?

Comment: Not necessarily, but typically I have them both aligned.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Intelij IDEA will use the JDK listed first is the PATH env vars, regardless of what's configured (atleast that's the behavior I've found on 2022.1.3).

I had the example same issue and swapped JDK11 & JDK17's order in the Path and it resolved my issue.

[image]

JDK 11 on top
[image]

JDK 17 on top
[image]